# How to search for specific zip file from the directory?

Tags: python, dataframe, zip

I have 100's of zip files in the following directory. How to search for the specific zip file from the directory. Search criteria could be `'date'` and `'salary'` of the zip. For example, file `abc_19980821_salary.zip`, this file belongs to the date 21-08-1998.

Please suggest how to search a folder like this:

```
 C:\Users\country
     abc_19980821_salary.zip
     xyz_20200829_salary.zip
     pqr_20050620_salary.zip
     stu_19990815_salary.zip
     klm_20040722_salary.zip
```

I want to search `pqr_20050620_salary.zip`:

```
with zp.ZipFile('C:/Users/country/pqr_20050620_salary.zip') as z:
    with z.open("file.TXT") as f:
        # read the dataset
        df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter = "\t")
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use glob to search for files using wildcards.

```py
import os
import glob
import datetime

top = r"C:\Users\jezequiel\Desktop"

d = datetime.date(1998, 8, 21)
ds = d.strftime('%Y%m%d')
pattern = f'*_{ds}_salary.zip' # use wildcards (*)

# make sure we have a match
with open(f'foobar_{ds}_salary.zip', 'wb') as f:
    pass

print(glob.glob(os.path.join(top, pattern)))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I can locate the exact zip file. In addition, how to access the files inside this zip?

Comment: What do you mean? You've already shown that you can use [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#module-zipfile) from your post above. If you want a list of names inside the zip file, you can use [namelist](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist). See also [infolist](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist) just above.

Comment: Thanks. I can access to all my files and your reply was super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Search for fname with some name

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

salary = 9000
date = datetime(2021, 3, 9)

data_fnames = os.listdir('.')
for fname in data_fname:
    _, date_raw, sal = fname.split('_')
    dt = datetime.strptime(date_raw, "%Y%m%d")
    if dt == date and sal == salary:
        with zp.ZipFile('C:/Users/country/pqr_20050620_salary.zip') as z:
            with z.open("file.TXT") as f:         
                df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter = "\t")
        break
```

Alternatively you can use regex expressions.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In your code, you mentioned 'klm' in fname but I want to search a zip file using date and salary as criteria. Because I dont know the exact name of the zip file, what I know is 'date' and 'salary' words containing in the file.

Comment: Corrected, should work for this particular case.